# powershell do not understand trace as part of text ex. $_.data-action-name

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer, automation

I am trying to automate a click on Internet Explorer, however the name in the document line has dash.

How to make powershell understand that dash is not an expression?

I tried this, but powershell don't understand the dashes:

```
$export = $ie.Document.getElementsByTagName('a') | where-object {$_.data-action-name -eq 'Csv'}
$export.click()
```

I need click where the word Csv appears:

```
<div class="action_group_contents">
   <a class="grid_async_export" data-ats-id="export-list-csv" data-action-name="Csv">CSV</a>
   <a class="grid_async_export" data-ats-id="export-list-xlsx" data-action-name="Xlsx">XLSX</a>
</div>
```

Thanks for yout help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a property name with special characters, you can simply quote the property name at retrieval.

```
$_.'data-action-name'
```

**Examples with Single and Double Quotes:**

```
> $obj = [pscustomobject]@{'data-with-dash' = "data"; 'data@with@at' = "data2"}
> $obj

data-with-dash data@with@at
-------------- ------------
data           data2

> $obj.'data-with-dash'
data
> $obj."data@with@at"
data2
```